# Covariance in interfaces and collections

Tags: c#, covariance

I'm trying to understand why the following doesn't work. Would anybody please care to explain?

The compiler warns that it "cannot convert from SomethingImpl to ISomething<IParam>", but the covariant definition of ISomething<TParam> does specify that TParam implements IParam , and the definition of ParamImpl implements IParam, hence I would conclude that ISomething<ParamImpl> can be stored in the list that expects elements of type ISomething<IParam>

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new List<ISomething<IParam>>();
    
    var myThing = new SomethingImpl();
    list.Add(myThing); // compiler complains about this line.
    list.Dump();
}

interface IParam {
}

interface ISomething<in TParam> where TParam : IParam 
{
}

class ParamImpl : IParam
{
}

class SomethingImpl : ISomething<ParamImpl>
{
}
```

Comment: `in` means "contravariant". Did you mean to use `out`? Is this a typo?

Comment: Change `in` to `out`, that should work